# EJS template .render() returns function instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, templates, ejs

I have an EJS template that I am trying to render with [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/):

```
new EJS({url: "assets/modules/templates/channel_filter.ejs"}).render();
```

Instead of returning the template contents I get a stringified function:

```
function(obj){var __p=[],print=function(){__p.push.apply(__p,arguments);};with(obj||{}){__p.push('
\n
\n Click channels to remove from results\n
\n
\n All Off\n All On\n
\n
\n
\n\n
\n
\n Apply\n Cancel\n
\n');}return __p.join('');}
```

The views are being rendered by AMD based javascript (require.js) and the server side system is Rails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because the rails asset pipeline was trying to interpret the files.

Comment: Would you please let us know how your solve this problem ?